# Session Variables, Hidden Fields and Tables

Tags: database, coldfusion, authentication, session-variables

Ok, would this work?

When a user logins a session variable is created. Then using the session variable I am able to put into a hidden field the correct user's ID number. The hidden field is in a form that allows the user to add comments. So from the hidden field the user ID is added to the 'comments' table from the 'users' table?

Thanks for the help. If it won't work, is there a reason why? What should I do to make it work if it won't?

Also, I'm using ColdFusion, MYSQL and Dreamweaver if it makes any difference. cheers.

Comment: When you have problems, please post sample code.  If you are making basic code errors, we'll be able to point them out.  If you have logic errors, we'll be more able to see them.

Comment: Just a point of clarification: If server sessions are enabled, a session is created for all visitors to that page, not just the visitors logged in. Here are how the steps would work:

User visits - session created

User Logs in - now you know who the user is. You may now store this in a session variable such as session.userid

The user fills out a form for comments, clicks save - now have some info you need in the session scope, I suggested session.userid, and the comments are available in the form scope, probably form.comments.

You may now run an insert or update cfquery with that data.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need hidden field of the user id on the form.

When the user send in a form, just access the session scope directly.

so.. when user logged in, store userid in SESSION.userid

when the form posted, get SESSION.userID and FORM.fieldXXX and go from there.

Comment: Moreover, you should *never* put something like the userid somewhere a user can edit it -- form, cookie, etc.  Keeping it in the session scope renders it uneditable, but as soon as you rely on the client to return it correctly, you're asking for impersonations.